# The value of the variable changes after onSaveInstanceState is called

Tags: android, fragment, android-memory, onsaveinstancestate

As far as I know `onSaveInstanceState` is called every time the app goes to background. If so then the app might still execute some code while it is in the background. So, I'm wondering what will happen if the state of variable `x` will be saved during onSaveInstanceState, the app will still continue execution in the background and will change the value of the variable `x`. A little bit later the process will be killed and the activity will be recreated (when the user will come back to app).

So, what would be the value of `x`? It seems that it will have an old value(saved during `onSaveInstanceState`), but what will happen to the new value, will it be lost?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the variables as you call them are not automatically saved you need to put them in a Bundle, similar to when you add Extras to an Intent.

And retrieve those values taking them out of the Bundle in the method `onRestoreInstanceState`. So the value of a certain variable, when restored would be the one you set in the Bundle if you later change that value and not put it on the Bundle it will be lost.

Also please take into account that this background execution as you called it, it is not so. It is just a minimal code execution to save the state of your activity not an actual background execution